# android: get image dimensions without opening it

Tags: android

I want to get width and height (in pixels) of images which are stored on the sdcard, before loading them into RAM. I need to know the size, so I can downsample them accordingly when loading them. Without downsampling them I get an OutOfMemoryException.

Anyone knows how to get dimensions of image files?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Pass the option to just decode the bounds to the factory:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

//Returns null, sizes are in the options variable
BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/image.png", options);
int width = options.outWidth;
int height = options.outHeight;
//If you want, the MIME type will also be decoded (if possible)
String type = options.outMimeType;
```

Comment: How can get the Density value?

Comment: returns 0 for height and width

Comment: If the uri is something like `"images/1234/get"` which is not include image format, is it possible to get the dimensions? @Devunwired

Comment: this still processes images, while checking multiple images it takes too long, decodeFile still processes the whole image even if it doesn't allocate memory for it.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is another way to solve this problem. Using the below way, we can avoid the trouble with file and URI.

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
ParcelFileDescriptor fd = mContext.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(u, "r"); // u is your Uri
BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fd.getFileDescriptor(), null, options);
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23867823/get-image-width-and-height-from-uri?lq=1.