# How to avoid out of memory errors in android when loading big bitmaps?

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

In android, I open a bitmap from the image picker, and load it into a imageview. If the user selects a big image, the app will crash. I tried try/catch, but it didn't work.

Is there a way to check the file size before loading it into a bitmap?

This is the code:

This is the return function from when I choose an image

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        ImageUploadHandler.handleResult(this, data);
    }
}
```

this is from another file

```
public void handleResult(Context context, Intent data) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    try {
        bitmap = MyImage.GetBitmapFromPath(context, data.getData());         
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);

        int size = out.size();
        isReady = size <= IMAGE_THRESHOLD;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        isReady = false;
        Log.d("Image Error", e.getMessage());
    }

    if (isReady) {
        DialogImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        DialogStatus.setText(context.getString(R.string.image_ok));
    } else {
        DialogImageView.setImageDrawable(null);
        DialogStatus.setText(context.getString(R.string.too_big_image));
    }
}
```

another file

```
public static Bitmap GetBitmapFromPath(Context context, Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String filePath = cursor.getString(column_index);
    cursor.close();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
    return bitmap;
}
```

This line

```
bitmap = MyImage.GetBitmapFromPath(context, data.getData());
```

from the handleResult function, causes a outofmemory error when a user loads a big image.

How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128481/android-get-image-dimensions-without-opening-it

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: this gives you the width and height, but not the size in bytes...

Comment: @omega The width and height is precisely the problem, not the file size.

Answer (score 0):

try code similar to this, you just need to get a File object from the Bitmap you intend to check:

```
File file = new File(uri); // or new File(filePath);
file.length() // should give you a file size in bytes
```

Comment: The memory needed to load a Bitmap depends on the bitmap's dimensions (i.e. width by height) and is not (necessarily) correlated to the file size.

Comment: How do you know the width/height threshold so it won't crash?

Comment: If you want the uncompressed bitmap size, you can't really rely on file size alone with my solution then. You could count the bytes read from a bitmap stream until you hit a target threshold you feel is too much and then abort that operation.